# Formatting the ArgParse help menu

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to create a more attractive menu for ArgParse mainly just consistent formatting when the help menu is displayed. I understand how to use various attributes to make something required or not, but am not sure how to format the text so that they are consistent.

My current code that is relevant is shown below

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myprogram', description='Select which files to parser and where to save them.')

parser.add_argument('-f', metavar='--file', type=str, help='select a single file to process', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-d', metavar='--dir', type=str, help='filepath directory', required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The output of this code is when running the command filename.py -h is
[image: Screen capture of terminal output]

What I would like to do is simply add a comma between -f and --file as well as any additional commands. I understand this is fairly small detail, but what can I say I like to format things consistently.

I am running Python v3.8.2 on my machine and Argparse v1.4.0

Comment: Drop `metavar=` from the `add_argument` calls. Only keep `'--file'`!

Comment: A more common argument definition would be: `parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='select a single file to process')`.  The user can then use `-f filename` or `--file filename`.  Your use of `--file` for the metavar will be confusing.

Comment: A default help line will be '-f FILE, --file FILE select ...'.  The repeated 'FILE' can replaced or shortened with the `metavar`, but not fully eliminated.  There have been SO asking for variations, especially more compact versions, but that requires subclassing the HelpFormatter, and modifying a method.  If you don't like formatting details, tweaking the formatter is allowed, and even encouraged; but don't expect a lot of hand-holding.

Comment: @hpaulj okay, that makes sense! It seems like there are a lot of arguments and its so confusing to know when to use them if at all. 

Could you speak to the HelpFormatter a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should illustrate the main help formatting possibilities (without subclassing the helpformatter):

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-f','--foo',action='store_true', help='a store true
   ...: ');
In [4]: parser.add_argument('-b','--bar',help='basic store');
In [5]: parser.add_argument('-x','--xxx', metavar='',help='blank metavar');
In [6]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f] [-b BAR] [-x]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f, --foo          a store true
  -b BAR, --bar BAR  basic store
  -x , --xxx         blank metavar
```

Comment: this makes so much sense! 

My only confusion now is where the 

usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f] [-b BAR] [-x] 

would be defined

Comment: `parser.format_usage` creates the usage line.  `format_help` does this plus adds the help lines.  Actual formatting is done by methods in the `HelpFormatter` class, specifically by a `_format_usage` method.  That method is somewhat brittle, and can be messed up by wrong characters in the `metavar`.  Formatting usage and help is a large task, involving as much code as parsing.